# no match for 'operator<<' C++

Tags: c++, windows, codeblocks

My program won't run I get an error message saying:

```
`error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::string' {aka 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>'} and '<unresolved overloaded function type>')|`
```

On the `cout << address, " ", street << endl;` line
I was using VS2017 but switched to CodeBlocks mid-way through
I have Windows 10 Pro Ryzen 5 2400G, 1060 6gb 16gb ram

Here is my program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string name, city, state, road, country, street;
    int address;
    cout << "Enter your: Name\n";
        cin >> name;
    cout << "Enter your Street\n";
            cin >> street;
    cout << "Enter your: Address\n";
        cin >> address;
    cout << "Enter your:\n City\n";
        cin >> city;
    cout << "Enter your: Province/State\n";
        cin >> state;
    cout << "Enter your: Country\n";
        cin >> country;
//Output
    cout << name << endl;
    cout << address, " ", street << endl;
    cout << city, " ", province, " ", country;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `cout << address, " ", street << endl;` --> `cout << address << " " << street << endl;`. Voting to close as typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong. You can't use `,` to chain arguments to `cout` like that. Instead do:

```
cout << address << " " << street << endl;
cout << city << " " << province << " " << country;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your last two statements are **syntactically incorrect**. They should be as follows -

```
cout << address<<" "<<street << endl; 
cout << city<< " "<< province<<" "<< country;
```

You probably are trying to use something like **python** in **C++**. But obviously that doesn't work. Each time you just have to keep doing `cout<< variable1 << " " << variable2<< " ";` . This is how chaining works in C++. **No shorthand to that**

I hope this solves your issue!

Comment: They are syntactically correct but semantically incorrect.  It would compile if there were an overload of `operator<<` defined for `street << endl` .